# Perl Concat String Truncates Beginning of Line

Tags: perl, variables, concatenation, truncate

I am running into a strange issue in perl that I can't seem to find an answer for.

I have a small script that will parse data from an external sorce (be it file, website, etc).  Once the data has been parsed, it will then save it to a CSV file.  However, the issue is when I am writing the file or printing to screen the data, it seems to be truncating the beginning of the string.  I am using strict and warnings and I am not seeing any errors.

Here is an example:

```
print "Name: " . $name . "\n";
print "Type: " . $type. "\n";
print "Price: " . $price . "\n";
print "Count: " . $count . "\n";
```

It will return the following:

```
John
Blue
7.99
5
```

If I attempt to do it this way:

```
print "$name,$type,$price,$count\n";
```

I get the following as a result:

```
,7.99,5
```

I tried the following to see where the issue begins and get the following:

```
print "$name\n";
print "$name,$type\n";
print "$name,$type,$price\n";
print "$name,$type,$price,$count\n";
```

Results:

```
John
John,Blue
,7.99
,7.99,5
```

I am still learning perl, but can't seem to find out (maybe due to lack of knowledge) of what is causing this.  I tried debugging the script, but I did not see any special character in the price variable that would cause this.

Comment: Using `printf()` with formatters, does the issue still arise?

Comment: printf has the exact same results.

Comment: There's possibly a strange char in `$type`. Try running your output through `hexdump -C`.

Comment: What does `length $type` return?

Comment: Mat, that worked.  Looking at it in hexdump found the hex char for 0d (Carriage Return) right after Blue in the $type field.

Comment: Ended up running dos2unix on the input file, that fixed it and it is fixed in code as well...  I would have never thought of looking at it through hexdump.

Comment: @jinanwow : Why don't you post the solution as an answer?

Comment: Oops, I hadn't seen the problem had been solved here.

Comment: How odd that two people voted to close the question as being "too localised" even though it's a FAQ..

Comment: Zaid: I wanted to give @Mat the opportunity to post the answer so he could get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Mat suggestion I ran the output through `hexdump -C` and found there was a carriage return (indicated by the hex value `0d`).  Using the code `$price =~ s/\r//g;` to remove the CR from the line of text fixed the problem.

Also, the input file was in Windows format not Unix, ran the command `dos2unix` to fix that.

Answer (score 5):

The string in `$price` ends with a Carriage Return. This is causing your terminal to move the cursor to the start of the line, causing the first two fields to be overwritten by the ones that follow.

You are probably reading a Windows text file on a unix box. Convert the file (using `dos2unix`, for example), or use `s/\s+\z//;` instead of `chomp;`.

If the CR made into the middle of a string, you could use `s/\r//g;`.